# Keyframe animation with javascript timer issues with outer circle rotating around inner circle working sometimes and not other times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm having an Issue with an animation. Basically the way I want it to work is there is three arrows in a circle that go around an inner circle and every 3 seconds it stops for 3 seconds and then continues to rotate. For some reason it keeps skipping the rotation every so often so instead of rotating smoothly it jumps and looks really off. I would really appreciate any help on this and I hope I have explained this well.

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container animation-banner-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="outCircle">
                <div class="rotate">
                    <div class="counterrotate">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.animation-banner-container {
    height: 450px;
    margin-top: -5%;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.outCircle  {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: url('https://gdxdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Outer-Text.png');
    background-size: 400px 400px;
    left: 175px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.rotate {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 100px !important;  
    background: url('https://gdxdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/inner-wheel.png');
    background-size: 400px 400px;
}

.counterrotate {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: url('https://gdxdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/temp-img.png');
    background-size: 400px 400px;
    padding: 150px !important;
    margin: -50%;
}

@keyframes circle-one {
    from { transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotateZ(120deg); }
}

@keyframes circle-two {
    from { transform: rotateZ(120deg); }
    to { transform: rotateZ(240deg); }
}

@keyframes circle-three {
    from { transform: rotateZ(240deg); }
    to { transform: rotateZ(360deg); }
}

@keyframes ccircle-one {
    from { transform: rotateZ(360deg); }
    to { transform: rotateZ(240deg); }
}

@keyframes ccircle-two {
    from { transform: rotateZ(240deg); }
    to { transform: rotateZ(120deg); }
}

@keyframes ccircle-three {
    from { transform: rotateZ(120deg); }
    to { transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
}
```

**JS**

```
 var seconds = 3000;
    var tid = setInterval(mycode, seconds);

    var start = 1;
    var slides = 1;

    function mycode(val) {
    if(!val) {
    
        /* Controls the Stop and Start */
        if(start == 1) {
            $(".rotate").css({"animation-play-state": "paused"});
            $(".counterrotate").css({"animation-play-state": "paused"});
            start = 0;

        } else {
            $(".rotate").css({"animation-play-state": "running"});
            $(".counterrotate").css({"animation-play-state": "running"});
         
            if(slides == 1) {
                console.log("Check Slides 1: " + slides);
                $(".rotate").css({"animation": "circle-one 3s infinite linear"});
                $(".counterrotate").css({"animation": "ccircle-one 3s infinite linear"});
                slides = slides + 1;
            } 
            
            else if (slides == 2) {
                console.log("Check Slides 2: " + slides);
                $(".rotate").css({"animation": "circle-two 3s infinite linear"});
                $(".counterrotate").css({"animation": "ccircle-two 3s infinite linear"});
                slides = slides + 1;
            }

            else if (slides == 3) {
                console.log("Check Slides 3: " + slides);
                $(".rotate").css({"animation": "circle-three 3s infinite linear"});
                $(".counterrotate").css({"animation": "ccircle-three 3s infinite linear"});
                slides = 1;
            }
            start = 1;
            
        } // Close else
        /* Close Controls the Stop and Start */

    } else {
        abortTimer();
            tid = setInterval(mycode, seconds);
        }
    }

    function abortTimer() { // to be called when you want to stop the timer
        clearInterval(tid);
    }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/garathd/cxtjsub1/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Timing of animations with javascript is always difficult, and often rather impossible to do it in an exact way: if javascript is busy with several other tasks in the meantime, an unpreditable latency can happen. So I wouldn't rely on javascript.

I should suggest to do it with pure css: always in time !

A testpage: http://clba.nl/experiments/rotating-arrow-circle.htm

In this page I've replaced the inner circle by a div with css only; your tmp image is not needed, and can be replaced by a smaller/faster image of the figure only (1.5kB instead of 36kB).

For the background see: [CSS Keyframe Animation with Delay Between Iterations](https://css-tricks.com/css-keyframe-animation-delay-iterations/) on css-tricks.com.

Comment: Welcome to Stack, Francky. Whenever possible please try pasting your code directly into your answer. Links go dead over time thus stripping your answer of the efficacy it originally had.

Comment: @Francky I appreciate your help this looks really good but unfortunately its not what I need and in fact the temp image is needed! and doesn't need to move. In fact the red part of the circle is the highlighter so say it is highlight over manager then a text box appears to the side with information about the manager and the temp image in the middle also changes to a picture/icon about the manager, leader or individual also each arrow will be set up as an image map

Comment: This definitely needs javascript to do what I want

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to get a fresh pair of eyes on this and have found the issue.(Thanks Conor). So basically I just needed to change the "infinite" to "forwards" in the animation so:

**From**

```
            if(slides == 1) {
                console.log("Check Slides 1: " + slides);
                $(".rotate").css({"animation": "circle-one 3s infinite linear"});
                $(".counterrotate").css({"animation": "ccircle-one 3s infinite linear"});
                slides = slides + 1;
            } 
            
            else if (slides == 2) {
                console.log("Check Slides 2: " + slides);
                $(".rotate").css({"animation": "circle-two 3s infinite linear"});
                $(".counterrotate").css({"animation": "ccircle-two 3s infinite linear"});
                slides = slides + 1;
            }

            else if (slides == 3) {
                console.log("Check Slides 3: " + slides);
                $(".rotate").css({"animation": "circle-three 3s infinite linear"});
                $(".counterrotate").css({"animation": "ccircle-three 3s infinite linear"});
                slides = 1;
            }
```

**To**

```
            if(slides == 1) {
                console.log("Check Slides 1: " + slides);
                $(".rotate").css({"animation": "circle-one 3s forwards linear"});
                $(".counterrotate").css({"animation": "ccircle-one 3s forwards linear"});
                slides = slides + 1;
            } 
            
            else if (slides == 2) {
                console.log("Check Slides 2: " + slides);
                $(".rotate").css({"animation": "circle-two 3s forwards linear"});
                $(".counterrotate").css({"animation": "ccircle-two 3s forwards linear"});
                slides = slides + 1;
            }

            else if (slides == 3) {
                console.log("Check Slides 3: " + slides);
                $(".rotate").css({"animation": "circle-three 3s forwards linear"});
                $(".counterrotate").css({"animation": "ccircle-three 3s forwards linear"});
                slides = 1;
            }
```

I have also updated my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/garathd/cxtjsub1/28/)